# how to access hook object using .validate from feathers-hooks-common

Tags: node.js, feathersjs

I'm trying to create a simple validator in my feathersjs app and I need to have access to `hook.app` so I can retrieve the `users` service and check for uniqueness. Below is my code

```
checkUniqueEmail = (values, hook) => {
 const userService = hook.app.service('users');
 //below is my validation
}
```

The problem is that the `hook` variable is returning `undefined` instead of the hook object. The feathers-hooks-common github code it shows that this should be possible since `hook` is being pass as the 2nd parameter. (see below)

```
const results = validator(getItems(hook), hook); // line 18
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

I found a good documentation about feathers-hooks-common validate. It is better explained here. https://eddyystop.gitbooks.io/feathers-docs-common/content/hooks/validation.html

Answer (score 0):

all you need to do is at create hook
//pass context or hook

```
create:[
   validate((values,context) =>validations.signupAsync(values,context))
]
```

//at validations.signupAsync

```
 clientValidations.signupAsync = (values,context) => {
        const userService= context.app.service('users')
    }
```